# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balance clones original instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have FFMPEG configurated on my original EC2 instance, and I have load balance activated.

When load balance create a new instance, FFMPEG will be installed in the new instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a package to be installed on every instance of your Elastic Beanstalk environment, then you should add a packages section to your ebextensions as explained here:
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

You can also run commands using ebextensions to customize ffmpeg. The page above also explains how to use commands.

ebextensions will form part of your app source zip file.